# Infimum of the multiple variable function near 0

Tags: functions, supremum-and-infimum

I have a function F(t1,t2). (t1 > 0 and t2 > 0)

[image]

I want to find a infimum of this function when (t1,t2) approaches to 0. I think that is not 0.

Comment: Since the summations invole only two terms, perhaps it would be easier to just write for ex. 
$$
a_1 t_1 + a_2 t_2
$$
instead of the sum?

Comment: I thought that it's compact with the sum ) .